# How to iterate over an Array of objects with Ext.iterate (or JS)?

Tags: javascript, arrays, extjs

I know there is plenty of answers for this question on the net, but still I can't make it work.

After a callback on a JSON POST, I'm retrieving an Array of Object.
On the console log of the browser, the array is like this :

```
 [Object, Object, Object, Object, Object, Object, Object, Object, Object, Object]
```

where inside each object, there is stuff like :

```
 id4blob: "1084"
```

so I assume the array could be like this (correct me if I'm wrong):

```
 [{id4blob: "1084"},{id4blob: "2008"}, [...]]
```

The array is stored in a variable called **stationsParse**

I want to iterate over these values, I've found

```
  Ext.iterate
```

So I did this :

```
Ext.iterate(stationsParse, function(key, value) {
   console.log(key + value);
});
```

and then tried this (which seems yo be the same but in pure JS)

```
for (key in stationsParse) {
  var value = stationsParse[key];
  console.log(key + value);
}
```

But none is working, nothing is displayed in my console.
Still, the function is well triggered, I can see it into Chrome console, but the for is ignored.

What Am I doing wrong ?
Is this the correct way to iterate over an array of objects ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you want to use vanilla JS to loop over an array, a simple `for` loop will do the the trick. Access the value of each object's `id4blob` property using dot notation.

```
for (var i = 0, l = arr.length; i < l; i++) {
  console.log(arr[i].id4blob)
}
```

The `for...in` loop is generally reserved for looping over an object's properties.

[Demo](http://jsfiddle.net/andyuws/6ALy7/)

Comment: @Andy The link is dead.

Answer (score 8):

Try something like this:

```
var stationsParse = [{id: 1, someproperty: 2}, {id: 2, someproperty: 101}];

Ext.each(stationsParse, function(ob){
  Ext.Object.each(ob, function(property, value){
    console.log(property, value);
  });
});
```

Here I am using Ext.each to iterate over each element in the stationsParse array. Each element in that array is an object. To iterate over each property in the object I use Ext.Object.each. Both 'each' functions take the variable you want to iterate over as its first parameter and a function as its second parameter. The function will be run on each element of the array/property of the object.

Comment: You can also use `Ext.iterate( object, fn, [scope] )` for both array and objects: the method delegates to Ext.Array.each if the given value is iterable, and Ext.Object.each otherwise. 
[Doc here](http://docs-origin.sencha.com/extjs/4.0.7/#!/api/Ext-method-iterate)

Answer (score 0):

I was able to make this work:

```
for (var i in family) {
    console.log( family[i]["name"] );
}
```

in this tutorial on [Codecademy](http://www.codecademy.com/courses/spencer-sandbox/4/2), where `family` is an array of objects.

The only difference I can see is the `var` in front of my iterator variable `i`.